# Не работает авторизация PHP PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, php7

Суть в том, что есть БД, форма для авторизации, отсылающая к следующему скрипту. Никаким образом собственно эта авторизация не работает, однако вставив несколько `var_dump()` и `count()` я понял, что после перевода объекта в массив массив пустой, отсюда получается, что `count()` возвращает 0. Однако я изменил `fetchAll()` на `fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)` и увидел, что второй `var_dump()` возвращает булевый false! Далее `count()` возвращает 1 и при любые значениях формы авторизация как будто проходит.

```php
<?php

require_once('db_connection.php');

if ($_POST['login'] == '' || $_POST['password'] == '')
  header("Location: /authorization.php");
else {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = :login AND password = :pass"; //Формируем запрос без данных
  $result = $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $result->bindvalue(':login', $_POST['login']);    //Заполняем данные
  $result->bindvalue(':pass', md5(md5($_POST['password'])));    //Заполняем данные. Знаю, что хэшировать пароли в md5 идея не очень, но этот проект тестовый.
  $result->execute( ); //Выполняем запросы
  var_dump($result);
  $result = $result->fetchAll(); //переводим обьект ПДО в массив данных, для удобной работы
  var_dump($result);
    
  if (count($result)>0) { //Если база вернула 1 значение, значит и логин и пароль совпали. отлично
    echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">Ура! Мы авторизировались!'; 
    $_SESSION['user'] = $result[0]; //сохраняем обьект пользователя в сессии
  } else echo '<meta charset="UTF-8">Логин или пароль не верный или пользователь не существует';

  echo count($result);
}

?>
```

Comment: Вроде до `Однако я изменил` было все нормально и должно бы работать. Зачем вы поменяли на `fetch`, который ожидаемо возвращает `false`, и затем применяете к нему `count()`?

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов `fetch` поменял ради любопытства. `count()` в `if` нужен, чтобы когда логин и пароль совпали, то условие сработало. `count()` в конце был нужен просто для теста. По итогу ничего не помогло.

Comment: Понятно. Тогда непонятно, что сейчас не так. Если совпадений нет, count возвращает 0 в пустом массиве - так и должно быть.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов смысл в том, что при вводе значений из БД (то есть правильных) оно тоже пустой массив возвращает.

Comment: У меня ваш код работает. У вас сам запрос точно данные получает, если ввести правильные логин-пароль? Попробуйте в bindvalue подставить строки, которые точно в бд есть.

Comment: Я убрал `m5(md5($_POST['password']))` и всё заработало. Почему так вышло?

Comment: Наверное, пароли хранятся в базе не в таком виде `m5(md5($_POST['password']))`, смотрите, как вы пароль записываете.

Comment: @МаксимСтепанов ну да, в регистрации этого нет, там просто так записывалось)

Comment: Не очень удачная модель, когда вы сравниваете пароль SQL запросом. Вы очень сильно ограничиваете список алгоритмов хеширования паролей (md5(md5() - по нынешним временам почти как пароль в открытом виде). Сейчас хорошая практика - запрашивать хеш для логина, если не найден - значит неавторизован, если найден - проверяем хеш.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смысл был в том, что скрипт `регистрации` записывал пароль без `md5(md5())`. В связи с этим сравнение введённого пароля с паролем из базы данных возвращало 0